# How to configure SMTP to save send mails?

Tags: smtp

can you please tell me how to configure SMTP to save send mails in Sent Items folder of my Mail.

NOTE: I am using yahoo mail credentials to send mails.

Comment: You should be more specific on what mail application / server you are using and if you are trying to do this within code. Add tags for these elements in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible using SMTP only.

SMTP is just for message delivery, it has no knowledge of your inbox and its folders tructure.

When you send a mail using your mail client (Outlook, phone, gmail, etc), it will :

1. use SMTP to send your mail
2. then use a different protocol (usually IMAP or MAPI) to move the message to your "Sent items" folder.

There are some exceptions : some mail providers will automatically copy to your sent items all messages sent by your account through their SMTP server. I believe gmail does that. that's not as easy as you maythink, since one must ensure the message is not ciped twice (once by the email client, another one by the SMTP server).